# Set Union Operator in xpath

Tags: xpath, set, union, operator-keyword

```
<xsl:variable name="targetReceiverService">
        <EMP_EMPLOC_MAL curr="4.0">MAL</EMP_EMPLOC_MAL>
        <EMP_EMPLOC_SIN curr="1.6">SIN</EMP_EMPLOC_SIN>
        <EMP_EMPLOC_CHN curr="7.8">CHN</EMP_EMPLOC_CHN>
        <DEFAULT curr="1.0">NONE</DEFAULT>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="targetCountryCode" select="$targetReceiverService/*[name() = $ReceiverService] | $targetReceiverService/DEFAULT"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$targetCountryCode "/>
```

why value display for $targetCountryCode is only MAL but not included NONE since the "|" mean

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:value-of`  only displays the value of the first node in the set. (at least with XSL 1)

You can probably display all of them with

```
<xsl:for-each select="$targetCountryCode">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```